# Getting old data from table and appending new one

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm having trouble getting existing data from the table and appending new one to it, similar to a commenting system. All I can see is the currently submitted data due to the trigger of `.click`.

I'm wondering if I still have to create a new query to get the existing data from the table then append the new one, or whether there is an easier way to do that. Here is my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<?php
     require_once('get.php');
 ?>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
   <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
   <title></title>
   <meta name="description" content=""> 
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
 </head>
    <body>
       <div id="wrap-body">
        <form action="" method="post">
           <input type="text" name="username" id="username">
           <input type="text" name="msg" id="msg">
           <input type="button" id="submit" value="Send">
        </form>
       <div id="info">
       </div>
        </div> 
    </body>
    <script>
         $(document).ready(function (){
            var username ;
            var msg ;
        $('#submit').click(function (){
             username = $('#username').val();
                msg = $('#msg').val();

            $.ajax({
                      type: 'POST',
                      url: 'get.php',
                      dataType: 'json',
                     data:{'username': username, 'msg':msg},
                      success: function (data){
                     $.each(data, function(i,item) {
                          $('#info').append("<p> you are:"+data[i].username+"</p> <p> your  message  is:"+data[i].mesg);
                          })
                       }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
    </html>
```

get.php:

```
       <?php
          $host='localhost';
          $username='root';
            $password='12345';
          $db = 'feeds';
          $connect = mysql_connect($host,$username,$password) or die("cant connect");
               mysql_select_db($db) or die("cant select the".$db);
               $username = $_POST['username'];
               $msg = $_POST['msg'];
               $insert = "INSERT INTO info(user_name,message) VALUES('$username','$msg')";
            if(@!mysql_query($insert)){
                  die('error insertion'.mysql_error());
                   }
               $get = "SELECT * FROM info ORDER BY id desc LIMIT 1";
               $result=mysql_query($get)or die(mysql_error());  
               $inside_counter =   mysql_num_rows($result);
                  $data=array();
                    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                     {
                      $data[] = array(
                      'username'=>$row['user_name'],
                      'mesg'=>$row['message'],
                      'counter'=>$inside_counter
                    );
                  }
                echo json_encode($data);
           ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are limiting the second query to 1 return, so therefore you are only getting one row back

```
$get = "SELECT * FROM info ORDER BY id desc LIMIT 1";
```

should be

```
$get = "SELECT * FROM info ORDER BY id desc";
```

Comment: im returning 'mesg'=>$row['message'] in the $data so my data[i].mesg will be as it is isnt?

Comment: Ignore that, you're limiting the return so you are only going to get one.

Comment: but if im not im going to iterate the whole rows again and ill get append on the previous rows isnt?

Comment: Could you please explain more clearly what is happening when you click the button?

Comment: just like a commenting system, the button will add what in the text field in to the database then retrieve it with the other data in the database

Comment: Sorry maybe I should be clearer. What is it doing now? Is anything working or does nothing happen?

Comment: it is working now but every time i click the submit it appends the new set of rows on the previous one but with the new column from the text field. its like they stack a new set of list with the new one but still the old stack of list is still in there, what i wanted is to just append the new one but i still can get the previous comments

Answer (score 0):

Try to edit like this

```
$('#info').append("<p> you are:"+data[i].username+"</p> Hello<p>"+data[i].msg);
```